# how to make text bold for detailedTextLabel in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, detailtextlabel

```
cell!.textLabel?.text = vehicle["vrn"].string
cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = stateString
```

I want to display `stateString` as `bold` and also tried to use `textLabel` instead of `detailedText` but it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the font property of the `detailTextLabel`like so:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15.0)
```

Comment: Answer is incorrect, you need to set the .font property not the .text

Comment: correct answer: cell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

Comment: You're right, it should be font, not text, my bad. But just setting the text color to black doesn't make it bold...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`font`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/font) property inside the `UILabel` class.

```
// You need to set the name of your font here 
cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
```

There are other options using the [`attributedText`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText)
 property but implies a little more of code, something like this:

```
// Define attributes to set
let labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)
let attributes :Dictionary = [NSFontAttributeName : labelFont]

// Create the attributed string
var attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "textOfYourLabel", attributes:attributes)
cell.detailTextLabel?.attributedText = attrString
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bold text label using story board, simply select **SHADOW colour** in attributes inspector to same of that Text colour. Its works for me try it....